# How Configure the Web site(Php) to run the Cordova Camera plugin code

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera

Is there any possible way to access camera from a php website that is converted into cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access camera from PHP.

but you can send the image to a php backend, using ajax query and cordova file plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Php file on server

```
<?php

// Set new file name
$new_image_name = "newimage_".mt_rand().".jpg";

// upload file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'upload/'.$new_image_name);
echo $new_image_name ;
```

HTML file on phone

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
        <title>PhoneGap app</title>
        <!-- Script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js" ></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-3.0.0.js' ></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            // take picture from camera
            $('#but_take').click(function(){      
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL 
                });
            });

            // upload select 
            $("#but_select").click(function(){
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, 
                    allowEdit: true,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
                });
            });

            // Change image source and upload photo to server
            function onSuccess(imageURI) {
                // Set image source
                var image = document.getElementById('img');
                image.src = imageURI  + '?' + Math.random();

                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey = "file";
                options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

                var params = {};
                params.value1 = "test";
                params.value2 = "param";

                options.params = params;
                options.chunkedMode = false;

                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                ft.upload(imageURI, "https://example.com/upload.php", function(result){
                    alert('successfully uploaded ' + result.response);
                }, function(error){
                    alert('error : ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                }, options);
            }
            function onFail(message) {
                alert('Failed because: ' + message);
            }
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="img/test.jpg" id='img' style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        <br/>

        <button id='but_take'>Take photo</button>
        <button id='but_select'>Select photo from Gallery</button>

    </body>
</html>
```